# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT not working in android 11

Tags: android, android-intent, android-11

I need to bring the app from background to foreground when push notifications arrives. This code
works fine on versions prior to 11.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    startActivity(intent);
    ...
}
```

But stops working in android 11. Any idea?
Thanks!!

Comment: AFAIK, Its not possible to start activities from the background since Android 10 unless your app meets one of the specific exceptions, see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions). Are you sure your app was in the background? Also `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` should have nothing to do with actually starting the activity, it just moves to it the front of the stack if it is already running.

Comment: @free_coupons_for_sale_1023 Thanks, you solved my problem. Adding the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission to the manifest already moves the app to the front of the stack, as you say. This is that I need. Thanks again. If you can write the comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting comment as answer:

AFAIK, Its not possible to start activities from the background since Android 10 unless your app meets one of the specific exceptions, see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions). Are you sure your app was in the background? Also `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` should have nothing to do with actually starting the activity, it just moves to it the front of the stack if it is already running.